# JQuery Element.append causes warning Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated

Tags: jquery, ajax

> [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is
>   deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's
>   experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

This warning is appearing to me while performing the loop.

I have this loop:

```
                var totalPages = 0;

                getPage();

                getPage = function() {
                    var page = listPages[totalPages];

                    $.ajax({
                        xhr: function () {
                            var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                            xhr.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
                                if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                                    loading_progress_text.innerHTML = evt.loaded / evt.total * 100 / listPages.length + "%";
                                }
                            }, false);
                            return xhr;
                        },
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: `../${page}/${page}.html`
                    }).done(function (page) {
                        totalPages++;

                        $("#listPages").append(page); //<-- This is the problem

                        if (totalPages == listPages.length) {
                            removeLoading();
                        } else {
                            getPage();
                        }
                    })
                }
```

When I put the line of code `$("#listPages").append(page);` in comment the warning disappears, but I need this code, what can I do to fix it?

Comment: What happens if you make getPage asynchronous like this: `getPage = async function()`

Comment: Are there any `<script>` tags in the fetched `page`? My guess is one of them is performing a synchronous AJAX request

Comment: @NicholasPesa nothing different will happen. Why would you expect otherwise?

Comment: NicholasPesa getPage is not defined / @Phil Yes it contains ajax requests on these pages (socket.on and ajax), but the problem would be these requests or the getPage () main code?

Comment: @NicholasPesa My mistake when I put async continues the deprecated warning

Comment: @customuserlink it will be in the requests made from those remote pages ie, nothing in the code shown in your question. Something is using `xhr.open(method, url, false)` where the last `false` parameter indicates that the request should be made synchronously

Comment: @Phil Seeing here none of the pages have request ajax, only socket.emit and socket.on. I forgot to mention, but this code is for grabbing additional pages from a main page that is also requested. But the ajax request code is exactly the same as getting the main page.

Comment: @Phil I hit CTRL-SHIFT-F on my visual studio code workspace and searched for $.ajax and no additional pages contain ajax request

Comment: How about `new XMLHttpRequest()`? jQuery also has other methods for AJAX like `$.get`, `$.getJSON`, `$.load` and `$.post`

Comment: I searched and have none of these methods in my files. And xhr only the question inside ajax. Could it be a JQuery bug?